# What is the difference between cortana and search?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-search, cortana

It seems that until Windows 7 or 8, there was a search box, on th bottom of the start menu.

In Windows 10 it seems that only Cortana is avaiable to search.

What is the difference, how and where the classic search is searching, and how it is on cortana ?

Thanks

Comment: Classic search searches through file index and like Windows explorer file search. But Cortana searches with online services also with the former and helps with other user services.

Comment: Cortana also shares your searches with MS, unless you apply various privacy restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cortana is your digital agent. She'll help you get things done.
One of the major changes to Windows 10 is the presence of Microsoft’s voice assistant, Cortana. Along with voice searches, you will be given “suggestions” that the voice assistant makes. This includes reminders for scheduled events in your calendar, ideas when you are searching the Web for something, alternatives when you are quizzing Cortana for information, and more.
Here are some things Cortana can do for you:

- Give you reminders based on time, places, or people.
- Track packages, teams, interests, and flights.
- Send emails and texts.
- Manage your calendar and keep you up to date.
- Create and manage lists.
- Chit chat and play games.
- Find facts, files, places, and info.
- Open any app on your system.

[What is Cortana](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17214/windows-10-what-is)

> The Search box on your taskbar makes it easier for you to search the
>   web and Windows. It also allows you to be able to turn on or off to
>   have Cortana give you suggestions, ideas, reminders, alerts, and more.
>
> The Cortana icon on your taskbar makes it easier for you to search
>   everywhere. Searching everywhere searches all below on your PC and
>   online with Bing (if turned on). Bing may also display ads in your
>   search results.
>
> - Settings = Searches for what you type from Windows
>     settings, and not online.
> - Files = Searches for what you type from
>     files on your PC when the locations and file types have been included
>     in your indexing options. Does not search online.
> - Web images = Searches for what you type from images online with Bing (if turned
>     on). Bing may also give you ads in your search results.
> - Web videos = Searches for what you type from videos online with Bing (if turned
>     on). Bing may also give you ads in your search results.

[Windows 10 Forum](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2854-hide-show-search-box-cortana-icon-taskbar-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: This is all wonderful. The question now is how to disable all these goodies.

Comment: I don’t think this answers the question. How are the two different? Is the “Files” section of Cortana identical to the search from Explorer? Is the search from typing after opening Start the same as Cortana search even when the user has purposefully opted to not set up Cortana?

Answer (score 0):

Cortana is a virtual assistant developed by Microsoft that offers voice-activated assistance and performs tasks based on user commands. It can perform searches, manage schedules, set reminders, and more.

Search, on the other hand, refers to the general act of looking for information or items within a system or on the internet. While Cortana can facilitate searches as part of its functions, search, in its broader sense, involves seeking information without the personalized assistance and additional features offered by Cortana.